# Laravel-4 Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

**What is the best way to validate amount in laravel?**

This is my code.

```
public static $rules = array(
    'date' => 'required',
    'payer' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required',
    'method' => 'required',
    'creditAmount' => 'required|integer'
);
```

I don't want to limit the user. But amount could be like simple ditigs 33 or in  the floating values like 33.45

Comment: it all depends on what the criteria for your amount is... does it have to be in a certain range? does it have a max, min?  does it have to be a certain number of digits? does it have to be one of a specific set of values?  There are built in rules for all of the above and then there is the capability to write your own rules... you need to be more specific in your question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
public static $rules = array(
  'date' => 'required',
  'payer' => 'required',
  'category' => 'required',
  'method' => 'required',
  'creditAmount' => array('required', 'regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/')
));
```

I'm no regex pro so you may need to tweak that part, but the point is you probably want to use the regex validator for something like this.

Answer (score 9):

May be you can can use as numeric:

```
  public static $rules = array(
    'creditAmount' =>'required|numeric'
   ));
```

I guess it works!